# System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.' App.Current.Resources["theme_bg_color"] = Color.White;

Tags: xamarin.forms

Trying to set the value of Color in ResourceDictionary. [App.xaml]

```
<Color x:Key="theme_bg_color">#3E98EB</Color>
```

Exception on the line shown below:

```
App.Current.Resources["theme_bg_color"] = Color.White;
```

Comment: I don't immediately see a problem. Here is what I would try next: As a test, what happens if, **before** that line of code, you run this line: `var oldValue = App.Current.Resources["theme_bg_color"];`? Using a debugger breakpoint, so you can step through the code, see `oldValue` in "locals Pane". I have two questions in mind: 1) Does this new line of code give some exception? If so, what? 2) If no exception, what value is shown for `oldValue`? (Not really sure where I'm going with this; just trying to learn more about what is going on.)

Comment: Also, in what method did you put that line of code? Maybe it needs to be moved a bit later in the startup sequence. It is odd that it works in one template but not the other. Does `App.Current.Resources` have the same `type` in both projects?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve As per you told, I added the code :                                                   
 var oldValue = App.Current.Resources["theme_bg_color"];                                                Please see the type and result. I shared the screenshot above.

Comment: thanks, I got the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expecting an object type, so need to convert into an object.

```
public static class ThemeHandler
{
    public static Dictionary<int, Color> DictColors = new Dictionary<int, Color>()
    {
        {0, Color.FromHex("#0A65C0") },
        {1, Color.FromHex("#C54786") },
        {2, Color.DarkSalmon },
        {3, Color.FromHex("#3E98EB") },
        {4, Color.FromHex("#66CCCD") },
        {5, Color.FromHex("#008069") },
        {6, Color.Teal },
        {7, Color.FromHex("#5F259F") },
        {8, Color.Purple },
        {9, Color.FromHex("#C71585") },
        {10, Color.DarkSlateGray },
        {11, Color.FromHex("#466599") },
        {12, Color.SlateGray },
        {13, Color.Gray },
        {14, Color.DimGray },
        {15, Color.FromHex("#121212") }
    };

    public static void SetTheme(ThemeColor color)
    {
        try
        {
            App.ThemeColor = color;
            int index = (int)color;

            // Reduce color dencity use (+), Increase color dencity use (-)
            var fadecolor = DictColors[index].WithLuminosity(DictColors[index].Luminosity + (DictColors[index].Luminosity * .15));
            App.Current.Resources["theme_bg_color"] = (object)DictColors[index];
            App.Current.Resources["icon_bg_color"] = index == 0 ? (object)Color.White : (object)DictColors[index];
            App.Current.Resources["sub_icon_bg_color"] = (object)DictColors[index];
            App.Current.Resources["theme_bg_fade_color"] = fadecolor;
            App.Current.Resources["theme_txt_color"] = (object)Color.White;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

> Also we can write like:

```
App.Current.Resources["theme_bg_color"] = (object)ColorDictionary[index];
```

> xaml:

```
BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource theme_bg_color}"
```

Comment: Every value type is auto-convertible to `object` in C# through boxing, why do you need the explicit cast? What difference does that make?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen - I know, My old code was like this :   
App.Current.Resources["theme_bg_color"] = ColorDictionary[index]; but it is not understanding, when I converted its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small example for your reference, which implements the setting of Color inside Application.Resources.

Here is the App.xml code：

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="ButtonTest">red</Color>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
           ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                Value="{StaticResource ButtonTest}" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then create Buttton in xaml.
For more information, please refer to
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries

Comment: I have also added the same code as you showed. But I need to change value dynamically on <Color x:Key="ButtonTest">red</Color> . Thats why I tried the code : App.Current.Resources["theme_bg_color"] = Color.White;